# "TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument" Instance error

Tags: python, object, arguments, instance

I have two classes,in the first one I create an instance of the second class and I execute a method of the second class, a method that starts a process.

t1.py

```
test = "t1"

def executeBase():
    base = baseNode.BaseNode()
    baseNode.BaseNode.executeBase(test, base) #error
```

and baseNode.py

```
class BaseNode():

    def __init__(self):
        self.eui48 = "01:00:00:00:00:00"
        self.port = 7919

    def executeBase(self, test, base):
        #I execute here a process
```

I got the error in line (#error).

```
  File "/testbench/testbenchPython/test/t1.py", line 20, in executeBase
baseNode.BaseNode.executeBase(test, base)
TypeError: executeBase() missing 1 required positional argument: 'base'
```

Isn't it possible to do this? If yes, what's the problem and how can I correct it?
I've tried passing the arguments in different ways but I didn't find the solution.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should call `executeBase` on your instance.Try this:

```
def executeBase():
    base = baseNode.BaseNode()
    base.executeBase(test, base)
```

Comment: This works, but it seems a bit strange for me to use a instance for calling a method and passing the instance in the method itself. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: You can run `baseNode.BaseNode` **()** `.executeBase(test, base)` on your code or just use the base instance properties - you're right, you don't need to pass to instance to itself.

Answer (score 0):

In this case

`def executeBase():
    base = baseNode.BaseNode()
    baseNode.BaseNode.executeBase(test, base) #error`

I'm guessing executeBase() func looking for self! instead of `baseNode.BaseNode.executeBase(test, base) #error` this line this may work `base.executeBase(test,base)`